# how to just remap the ctrl and caps within emacs, and how to remap esc and caps only in vim

Tags: emacs

I use ubuntu12.04 and vim as develop tools. I am learn emacs and know a litter now.
it's seems every suggest to remap the ctrl and caps , but I still have to use vim and others.
so is there anyway to just remap the ctrl and caps within emacs.

Comment: Why would remapping ctrl and caps prevent you from using vim or other programs? The alternate remapping that you see suggested was the [default on many keyboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lk201.jpg), and people used `vi` and other programs just fine.

Comment: well，thank you for the suggest. I would like to have a try.

Answer (score 0):

well, It seems really good for me. the change is really nice.

But I have a question. How to modified the ctrl to caps. But in vim modified the ESC to CAPS.